# Is it standard C++

Tags: c++

This code is written in `C`:

```
int main(){
char Demoshellcode[] ="\xEB\x5D\x5F\x8B\xF7\x80\x3F";
void* addr=0;
addr=&Demoshellcode[0];
__asm call addr
return 0;
}
```

Can we consider it also as a standard`C++` code? If not, What modifications are needed to make it as a standard`C++`code?

Comment: If your question is really "how can I call functions defined at run-time", the answer is that in standard C++, you can't.

Comment: I believe a conforming implementation is allowed to accept this code, but it is totally non-portable. It "works" on systems that implement the `__asm` extension as executing code, allowing data to be executed, and where the hex values are also valid machine instructions. A rather limited target.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'll take 'standard' to exclude extensions but not implementation defined behavior (which is pretty much impossible to avoid anyway) or conditionally supported features.

No, the example is not standard because `__asm` is an extension. You'd have to use the standard `asm(...)` (with implementation defined behavior) but VC++ does not support `asm()`.

You could also convert the pointer to a function pointer (which is conditionally supported in C++11 with implementation defined behavior) and call that.

```
int main() {
    char Demoshellcode[] ="\xEB\x5D\x5F\x8B\xF7\x80\x3F";
    void (*func_ptr)(void) = reinterpret_cast<void (*)(void)>(&Demoshellcode);
    func_ptr();
}
```

I don't actually know if the above behaves as desired on any implementation. On modern systems you'll have to deal with the NX bit (which allows memory to be marked such that instructions stored in that memory cannot be executed).

(Converting an object pointer to a function pointer was an extension over C++03, but C++11 added it as a conditionally supported feature.)

Comment: The name is reserved for use in a possible implementation  specific extension.

Comment: Implementation defined. As you don't know if the caller or calle is supposed to tear down the stack frame (or whatever calling mechanism is supported by the architectures ABI).

Answer (score 4):

It's not, `__asm` is not standard.

`asm`, however, is.

Also note that it is implementation-defined:

> An asm declaration has the form
>
> `asm-definition:`
>
> `asm ( string-literal ) ;`
>
> The asm declaration is conditionally-supported; its meaning is implementation-defined. [ Note: Typically it is used to
> pass information through the implementation to an assembler. —end note ]

Comment: Downvote comment? It contains the same information as the highest voted answer, odd.

Comment: @GManNickG The answer was edited. The question was also different.

Comment: it won't let me take the downvote back, even though both the question and this answer are different now. :/

Comment: @ColinD that's fine, at the moment of the downvote the question was already edited and the answer was, indeed, not correct in regards to the new question. ;)